# video gets stuck in one frame for a long time about WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

When I test the result of WebRTC communication by using chrome, I find that sometimes the video stream is not fluent and it always gets stuck in one frame of the video.So I try to limit the bandwidth in the LAN to see whether it is my problem of misusing the WebRTC or it is the problem of WebRTC itself. In the end, I find that the video may get stuck at different bandwidth,maybe 40K/s,50K/s or even 60K/s. I get confused of the result.

Comment: Have you checked the log information in console?

Comment: How are you limiting the bandwidth(hopefully through adding a line to the SDP because any other way does not work)? Is this in a browser or native? What resolution are are capturing the video in? What framerate? How powerful are the two PCs you are streaming between?

Comment: There is no other log information in the console. I use 360 to limit the bandwidth of the Chrome(I don't know how to test it through adding a line to the SDP. Could you tell me ?) It is in a browser. The two PCs are OK . I don't know how to test other information like resolution,framerate.

Comment: So what is the problem? what error what code what help you need?